# How to find the Internal IP Address of GCP Cloud DNS server hosted in Private Zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I was trying to find the IP Address of DNS server hosted in private zone in GCP to resolve some traffic routing related issue on the firewall. But i am not able to find it in Cloud DNS GUI console.

Comment: Cloud DNS private zones require that you use the Google Cloud metadata server for name resolution. Its responding metadata server is 169.254.169.254. Is this what you are looking for?
https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/troubleshooting#query-dns-name-using-metadata-server:~:text=Cloud%20DNS%20private%20zones%20require%20that%20you%20use%20the%20metadata%20server%20for%20name%20resolution.

Comment: Look at my answer here to assign an IP address to an internal DNS server. Review Step 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66648321/8016720

Comment: @user260834  Did you get the answer that you are looking for? If so, please post it as answer so other members with the same question can see it.

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud DNS Private zones](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/troubleshooting#query-dns-name-using-metadata-server:%7E:text=Cloud%20DNS%20private%20zones%20require%20that%20you%20use%20the%20metadata%20server%20for%20name%20resolution) require that you use the metadata server for name resolution. Compute Engine instances receive internal DNS resolution information as part of their DHCP leases. By default, the [instance's metadata server (169.254.169.254)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#access_by_internal_DNS) resolves internal DNS names. If you change the name server configuration for your instance, you cannot resolve records in Compute Engine internal DNS (the .internal zone) or in Cloud DNS managed private zones, forwarding zones, and peering zones unless your replacement DNS server forwards these queries to 169.254.169.254.